# focusing and following an object in a swing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane

i want to focus and keep following a moving object(an image or drawn shape) which is inside a JPanel.tried using JScrollPanes but could not get the scroll pane to follow the object when it goes out of the view-able frame.

thanx.

Comment: which OS you have? Mac or Windows?

Comment: i use windows               .

Comment: Good luck with that.  Did you have a question?

Answer (score 3):

```
panel.scrollRectToVisible(...);
```